# How to make a heat-based county map of United States in R?

Tags: r, maps

I have data for the # of cows in about 1,500 counties across the United States. I would like to make a map of the United States with the counties colored in a shade weighted based on the #cows. The FIPS is a score that corresponds to a county. Is there a package that allows me to do this?

```
cows alligators  FIPS
4      0 45001
9      1 22001
3      0 51001
113    2 16001
1      0 19001
2      0 29001
```

Comment: This is currently too broad, and asking for package recommendations is off-topic for SO. What you're asking for is probably a choropleth, not a heatmap. There is a package choroplethr that I haven't used, but you might try just looking around for choropleth tutorials instead

Comment: So there isn't some easy way, if you have FIPS matched with a variable, to just plop that data into a US county map?

Comment: That's going to depend on things like what type of shapefiles and packages you're working with and how exactly you're trying to show this. That's the part that's too broad, so I'd recommend finding some tutorials that might help you figure out the approach you want

Comment: I don't have any shapefiles, I only have the above data. I am just trying to plot the color red (darker = more cows), based on the FIPS county.

Comment: if you use something like the `tigris` package you can access county-level shapefiles and it will include the fips code--you can merge on that

Answer (score 1):

[image: Fantasy -Us - cows 2020]

As a starter, cowboy!

```
## some lonely cows
df<-data.frame(cows=c("4","9","113","1","2"),
           fips =c(45001, 22001, 16001,19001, 29001))

## all Fips
maps::county.fips %>%
  as_tibble %>% 
  extract(polyname, c("region", "subregion"), "^([^,]+),([^,]+)$") -> dfips

## some county maps & left_join

map_data("county") %>% 
  left_join(dfips) -> data

## more left_join
data<-left_join(data,df)

## character cows
data$cows<-as.numeric(as.character(data$cows))

### more cows
data[["cows"]][is.na(data[["cows"]])] <- 100

## even more random cows

data$cows<-ceiling(rnorm(length(data$cows),600,200))

## map with random, fictive cows
data %>%   ggplot( aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=cows)) +
  coord_map() +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "A")+
  ggtitle("Fictive random cows of the United States of America", subtitle = "“In a county near YOU!”")
```

Comment: this is awesome! How do I pick the two colors and gradient between them?

Comment: I get an error `Error: Can't find columns `region`, `subregion` in `.data`.` when using your code